# Add Facebook share button to Django application

Tags: django, facebook

I am using Facebook's share button on my Django app.

I'm using Facebook's SKD instructions which tell me to place this code wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" 
    data-href="https://my-website-full-url" 
    data-layout="button" data-size="small" data-mobile-iframe="false">
       <a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share
       </a>
</div>
```

So I placed that code in my template but how do I add the full URL of the web page with the FB share button in the **data-href** attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have [`django.template.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-request) enabled you should be able to use [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) in your template:

```
data-href="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}"
```

This should work out of the box if you're using a fairly recent version of Django.